# I'm trying to get my discord bot to wait for the user to send another message after they did the original command

Tags: python, discord.py

Sorry if the title didn't make sense, I'm making a discord bot and I'm trying to make a little 8 ball command. What I'm trying to make the bot do is that after the user type "$8ball" the bot will say "What's your question?" Then wait for the user to type out their question and then respond with the array of responses I've made for it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author == client.user:
   return

if message.content.startswith("$8Ball"):
   await message.channel.send("What is your question?")
```

(that's all the code I have so far)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `question` will be what the user inputted. It waits for a message in the same channel as the orginal command and by the same user who did the command

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message, author):
    if message.content.startswith('$8Ball'):
        channel = message.channel
        author = message.author
        await channel.send('What is your question?')

        def check(m):
            return m.author == author and m.channel == channel

        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        question = msg.content
```

Tell me how it goes :D

Comment: Ok, sorry if you saw my earlier comment about it not working, I had it set up wrong lol. Thank you so much this helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store the id of the user and react to the next message of this user.